# Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, oop, redeclare

PHP says "Cannot redeclare class MyClass". Of course, class is defined only once. What else can cause this error?

Comment: More than likely you're including/requiring a script more than once. You can avoid this via `include_once()` or `require_once()`.

Answer (score 1):

A class included / required more then once. *always*  use the `include_once` / `require_once` syntax for class & function files.

Answer (score 1):

This was because my class was named `Directory`. It is probably a library class.